# Is there a form of euhemerism which claims myths can have historical events derived from them like a poetic?

Tags: psychology, myths, philosophy-of-history, literary-theory

Is there a form of [euhemerism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euhemerism) which claims myths can have historical events derived from them like a poetic?

I gather that the theory states that myth is a way of ordering chaotic human history. Obviously it could not replace scholarship, but has anyone claimed that the actual event is transcribed in the literature and can be unpacked via close reading and familiarity with similar works, rather than history as a science?

Comment: What do you really mean with "**Is there** a form of euhemerism ... ?". [Euhemerus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euhemerus) existed (late 4th century BC), and an "euhemeristic approach" to religion is in [Lucretius](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lucretius/#Religion) : "Here Lucretius follows a trend which had gathered pace after Epicurus' own day, the rationalistic practice - **associated with the name of Euhemerus** - of explaining the gods as pioneering human benefactors whose service had been institutionally acknowledged by formal divinization."

Comment: More recent euhemeristic approaches are found in the e Early modern period from the 16th, with e.g. the French historian [Antoine Banier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_Banier) in his *Mythologie et la fable expliqués par l'histoire* (1711) and the  British scholar [Jacob Bryant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Bryant) with *A New System or Analysis of Ancient Mythology* (1744).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA not sure i understand?  i saw the word used in a discussion of post modern poetry